# "Inject" interface implementions into a class in java

Tags: java

I'm wrting something that look like this (of course its a bit more complex than this sample):

```
public class DoOnAll {

    private List<IActionPerformer> actionPerformers;

    public DoOnAll(List<IActionPerformer> actionPerformers) {
        this.actionPerformers = actionPerformers;
    }

    public void callFromSomeWhere(String path) {
        File f = new File(path);
        List<File> list = Arrays.asList(f.listFiles());
        for (File file : list) {
            for (IActionPerformer action : actionPerformers) {
                action.perform(file);
               }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public interface IActionPerformer {
    public void perform(File file);
}
```

---

```
public class SomePerformer implements IActionPerformer {

    public void perform(File file) {
        if (getFileType(file) = ".txt") {
            doSomething
        }
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Should I move the condition in `SomePerformer` to another method, `boolean accept(File file)` for example, and also add this method declartion to the interface?
   If so, how would I "collect" all the accepted classes in `DoOnAll`? just go through the `actionPerformers` list and add all the accepeted  to another list and then go through the list of accepted and `.perform` on them? Or is there another way usually used in the methodology?
2. Which ways are there for injecting the `actionPerformrs` list into the class? 
   I want to write independent implementations and define in a file, say xml file, which ones to inject into the list.

Comment: Is the `TraverseDirecotry` (sic) meant to be `DoOnAll`?

Comment: Is TraverseDirecotry a typo for the DoOnAll constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your second question, you should look into [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Java has a few good frameworks that can do this for you, for example:

- [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)
- [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/)

Spring in particular allows you to define your application's components and dependencies in XML files. For examples see:

- [The IoC Container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html), in particular
- [Injecting Dependencies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators).

This last link has a subsection on constructor injection: creating java objects with dependencies supplied to their constructors, as your class `DoOnAll` requires.

Comment: Can you add a simple example of how this is done with spring? In particular, how do I define DoOnAll class as a one that its property actionPerformers should ask the xml for injection?
Also, I generally know that spring given many abilities. Is it possible if I use spring to somehow put conditions inside the xml file, say somehow move the condition on the file type to the xml?

Comment: What if I want the xml file to be outside of the classpath?

Comment: @AAaa see http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.html

Answer (score 3):

WRT question 2: I agree with Dan, Spring or Guice.

WRT question 1: IMHO I would not create a conditional method as part of the interface. Either way you must call one method on each object, why call two? Let the object determine for itself if processing should be done. This also prevents any potential overhead in invoking multiple methods on the class. It also makes the calling method more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1. What you described is a chain-of-responsibility pattern. You can also check if a Performer can execute on file, of no - use next performer from a list. If no performes left - exception. You can use another method or make your `perform` method return true/false of throw exception if it can't perform.

Question 2. Use Spring in a simplest manner. Do it like:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("some_configuration.xml");
```

You can also try Google Guice.

Comment: Not really Chain-of-Responsibility as in that pattern, the first object to take responsibility is the last one called. You keep iterating over elements until you find one that is able to handle the situation. Here, the asker wants each element that can process the value to do so.

Answer (score 2):

General suggestions here:

1. Start simple (with what you have), and extend your interface when you have a use (case) for it. I'd just do `if (accept(someFile)) perform(someFile);` in an AbstractPerformer.performIfAccepted(File) method.
2. See other answers, I'm no expert in this area.

Answer (score 2):

**1)** First off keep it simple... I think you need to decide what it is you want to do. Is it to (a) give a first responder the chance to respond to the presence of a file of a certain type, (b) allow all possible responders for that type to respond or (c) to identify a single specific responder to a file type.

If:

a) See Peter Gwiazda's answer (IMO).

b) Similar to (a) but permit multiple responders in the chain.

c) Where there is always a specific responder to a file type, you could use a factory to obtain a specific instance based on the file type. This hides the specifics of the implementation. There are disadvantages in an IoC environment but the factory can still be populated using IoC if required.

**2)** Check out "Inversion of Control" metaphor in general and Spring in particular (as already suggested).